# Получение IPv4-адресов в php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день. В php копаюсь пару дней. Достаточно плохо понимаю регулярные выражения и то, как с ними работать, поэтому прошу помощи здесь. Надеюсь на понимание.

Есть определённая страница (url) со следующим содержанием:

```
TOTAL : 3, id=001, ...
IP Address(es):
ipv4: 1.2.3.4, ...
ipv4: 5.6.7.8, ...
ipv4: 12.253.789.25, ...
```

С помощью php мне нужно получить каждый ip-адрес (1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8, 12.253.789.25) в столбик.
Чтобы я мог вывести их подобным образом в своем php-файле:

```
1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
12.253.789.25
```

Также хочу сказать, что этих ip-адресов может быть достаточно много, около 1000. Буду рад любой помощи, т.к. уже несколько дней мучаюсь.

Comment: `12.253.789.25` - IPv4???

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

В отличие от [решения ув-мого Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513130/199934), данным регулярным выражением находятся только те значения, где до, между и после точек одна, две или три цифры, что выражено шаблоном `{1,3}`. То есть выведется `12.253.789.25`, но не `12.2534.789.25`, — это как раз и требуется для поиска `IPv4`-адресов. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает исправно. В примере я действительно допустил ошибку с одним ipv4 12.253.789.25, однако в реальности подобных ошибочных ip там не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Регулярное выражение для поиска `IPv4`:

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)
```

Проверить можно [тут](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Если не требуется проверять на валидность, то просто

```
\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+
```

Comment: Это не `IPv4`, а четыре числа разделённых точками и без сохранения как ссылки в результате поиска.

Comment: @Other, я знаю. Но обычно не следует мудрить, если для этого нет причин.

Comment: Ну не знаю, сказано `IPv4`, значит нужно искать то, что подходит под это определение и уж точно не найдёт `0.123.456.789` :)

Comment: @Other, но для того, чтобы оно это нашло, надо, чтобы оно там было :) Маловероятно, что там есть какие-то случайные числа группами по 4 через точку. А если они есть, то они ведь тоже могут образовывать корректный ip-адрес, значит нужен другой признак. Вывод: подгонка регулярки под корректные значения нужна только если стоит задача отфильтровать корректные ip-адреса от некорректных. В остальных случаях это либо не требуется, либо всё равно не сможет полностью решить задачу.