# Точное регулярное выражение по нахождению IPv4-адресов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pcre

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513174/199934) я предложил пример регулярного выражения, которое, однако, будет находить и числа в промежутке между 256 и 999, что уже [не IPv4](http://itandlife.ru/technology/computer-networks/ip-adresaciya-klassy-ip-adresov-i-znachenie-maski-podseti/). Наткнулся в книге на более точный шаблон:

```
(((\d{1,2})|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(25[0-5]))\.){3}((\d{1,2})|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(25[0-5]))
```

Но [**тестирование показывает**](https://regex101.com/r/uJ0hU7/1), что он прямо ошибочен, поскольку отсекается последняя цифра IP-адреса. Видимо, т. к. в модели стоят операторы `|` (или), обработчик регулярных выражений выбирает из двух возможных вариантов — к примеру, `20` и `200`, — тот, который покороче.

Логично предположить, что я где-то допустил синтаксическую опечатку. Но выверял несколько раз, так и не отыскал оной.

[image: Пример из книги]

В книге подсвечивается `200`, а у меня `20`. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё решается очень просто.
Достаточно более длинные варианты альтернатив поставить перед более короткими.
Альтернативы в регулярных выражениях, можно сказать, имеют приоритет слева направо.

```
(((\d{1,2})|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(25[0-5]))\.){3}((\d{1,2})|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(25[0-5]))
```

https://regex101.com/r/uJ0hU7/2

Данное регулярное выражение обладает более серьёзной проблемой: в IP-адресе могут быть ведущие нули. Разве недопустима запись `010.010.010.010` ?

Не знаю, где Вы нашли это регулярное выражение, но первый же результат из поиска `regex ip4` лишен всех этих проблем:

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/uJ0hU7/3

Comment: У меня матчит 300.0.0.0

Comment: @polRk, ни первое, ни второе регулярное выражение, приведённое мной не совпадает с указанным Вами текстом. Возможно, Вы не учитываете, что приведенные мной выражения не учитывают границы текста, поэтому в тексте 300.0.0.0 совпадает часть текста 00.0.0.0 . В постановке вопроса не требовалось учитывать границы, поэтому они не учитываются и в моём ответе.

Comment: В задании четко сказано: которое, однако, будет находить и числа в промежутке между 256 и 999, что уже не IPv4.

Comment: @polRk, Вы не совсем поняли что я имею ввиду под границами текста. Смотрите https://regex101.com/r/TbeR93/1 это регулярное выражение учитывает границы текста.

Comment: Спасибо!  Обновите ваш ответ, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Я бы дополнительно ужесточил регулярное выражение:

```
^((25[0-5]|2[4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/wkxYGz/2/

В варианте, предложенном ранее, в выборку попадают некорректные адреса вида:

001.234.100.1.1

336.245.123.4

Comment: Комментарий от пользователя из предложенных правок: Выражение не работает для 0.0.0.206

Comment: Не работает 46.61.155.237

Answer (score 0):

> Видимо, т. к. в модели стоят операторы `|` (или), обработчик регулярных выражений выбирает из двух возможных вариантов — к примеру, `20` и `200`, — тот, который покороче.

Если проблема действительно заключается в этом, то надо просто переставить выбираемые через `|` варианты в порядке уменьшения их длины.

Однако можно заметить, что чего-то типа `7891.2.3.4000` скорее всего выберется `91.2.3.40`, потому я не вижу никаких проверок на символы по краям и адрес может вытаскиваться из любого текста.